# MVC File Download Not Working in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have seen numerous questions and posts concerning returning a File to a view and refreshing etc. My issue is that the return works in Firefox, Chrome, etc., but not IE.  When the same code is executed in IE it actually refreshes the view but I get no file. I have a click handler in the script on the aspx

```
    function RunReport(iExport) {
        var fromDate = "";
        var toDate = "";

        fromDate = viewModel.FromDate;
        toDate = viewModel.ToDate;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Reports/RunReport',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { 'fromdate': fromDate, 'toDate': toDate, 'doExport': iExport },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == "true") {
                    location.reload();         
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //notify.show({type: 'error', header: "Error applying Filters!", content: "Unable to apply filters." + e });
            }
        });  
    }
```

The `RunReport` action sets some variables, returns a true result and then the page reloads examining the `iExport` variable.

During the load of the page (`ActionResult Index()`) the data is refreshed using some filters and variables that have been set. And then if `iExport = 1` it does:  `return ExportReport(model);`

Export Report:

```
    public FileContentResult ExportReport(ReportViewModel model)
    {
        string sCSV = "";
        sCSV = DoSomeProcessingToGetCSVString...;
```

// I have tried this with and without the header

```
        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            // for example foo.bak
            FileName = "Test.csv",

            Inline = false,
        };

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sCSV), "text/csv", "Test.csv");
```

}

when it returns file it actually just refreshes/reloads the page calling the Index() action result again and it never produces the download.  this does work in other browsers and does not refresh the page

when initially receiving the iExport = 1 I reset that to null so returning to the page will not keep exporting.  if I comment that out and let it stay = 1 then the second time it loads it does export out the file but of course navigates to a blank page.

Is there a better way to do this or is there a problem with IE (I am on IE11)?